# Why is CABasicAnimation not animating to the correct point?

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer, cabasicanimation

I am adding a containerView to my app. This views view and layer are at the normal 0,0 point and 320,480. Nothing exciting or different.

So I add it to my view, but I want to animate it on screen via its layer. Again nothing to crazy. But I want this view/layer of my added view to be at a point of 20,160. So 20 pixels from the left and half way down the window (bottom half the of the window). I would think I would set my animateToPoint for the CALayer to be 20,160. But it doesn't work.

Below is my code, which does animate the added view/layer to 20 pixels from the left and halfway down the screen. The issue is, the point I am passing in to make it 20,160 is completely wrong but it works (I had to move it via trial an error). My question is why doesn't 20,160 work for the CABasicaAnimation point? Why do I have to put in such large numbers?

```
    // Place the container view
        self.callDetailView.view.frame = CGRectMake(20, 163, 280, 263);
        self.callDetailView.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

        [self.view addSubview:self.callDetailView.view];
        [self addChildViewController:self.callDetailView];
        [self.callDetailView didMoveToParentViewController:self];

        [self.callDetailView configureDetails:[[STRequestManager sharedInstance] shouldGetCurrentRequest]];
        CGPoint myNewEndPoint = CGPointMake(160.0,  263.0); // <-- I would think this should be 20,160
        CABasicAnimation *slideIn = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
        slideIn.duration = 0.5;
        [slideIn setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:myNewEndPoint]];
        [slideIn setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(160.0,  663.0)]];
        [[self.callDetailView.view layer] addAnimation:slideIn forKey:@"mySlideInAnimation"];
        [[self.callDetailView.view layer] setPosition:myNewEndPoint];
```

//UPDATE

Now that I look at the 160,263 is the vertical center point and horizontal center point. My view I am adding is 280 so half that is 140. 140 plus my 20 from the left is 160. Does CABasicAnimation animate the center?

Answer (score 0):

By default the `AnchorPoint` of a layer is (0.5, 0.5) i.e. Center. Hence your animation is moving along the Center.